# Kendo-UI line-chart not updating

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

The line chart is not getting updated when I update the datasource with new data.
All the other chart types are updating when I change their datasource. I noticed that the line-chart updates if I do a window resize.

Check my code on stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ojyf6g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the reference of your data source, instead of updating it.

```js
public addNewValue() {
    const newItem = {
      "Value": Math.random()*100,
      "Timestamp": "2019-11-26T14:34:59.203Z",
      "IsError": false
    }
    this.adata = [...this.adata, newItem];
    console.log(this.adata);
}
```

This is what is recommended in the [documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/chart/data-binding/#toc-updating-data).